# LU decomposition using openmp

Tags: c++, c, openmp, linear-algebra

I have a problem: parallel version of LU decomposition algorithm is running same time as sequence:

```
void lup_od_omp(double* a, int n){

int i,j,k;

for(k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for shared(a,n,k) private(i,j)
    for(i = k + 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        a[i*n + k] /= a[k*n + k];
        for(j = k + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            a[i*n + j] -= a[i*n + k]*a[k*n + j];
        }
    }
}}
```

Maybe i'm doing something wrong?

Comment: how long does the single thread version run?

Comment: same time as parallel: ~8s for 2000*2000 Matrix

Comment: How many CPU cores do you have? Which OS/compiler do you use? Have you enabled openmp support in your compiler?

Comment: You have a major issue of false sharing. But aside from that: where do you use `p`?

Comment: Intel Core 2 Duo (2 cores without HyperThreading), Windows 7 32bit, Visual Studio 2010: openmp enabled in project properties.
P.S. Sorry, forgot to delete unused argument in function signature.But problem still exist :)

Comment: Higher optimization level could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are only working on two cores your parallelisation may actually get in the way of the vectoriser. Vectorisation on SSE2 will give you a data bandwidth of 2 doubles per op, 4 on AVX.

Dual thread has a lot of synchronisation overhead which may slow you down especially if you loose vectorisation. Also for some reason your `#pragma omp` does not start any threads unless `omp_set_num_threads` was invoked to actually make it use threads.

Another thing which is also related to vectorisation is that not all compilers understand that `a[i*n + j]` is intended to address a two-dimensional array, so it's better to declare it as such in the first place.

Here is a slight optimisation of your code that runs fairly well on my Xeon:

```
void lup_od_omp(int n, double (*a)[n]){
    int i,k;

    for(k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k) {
        // for the vectoriser
        for(i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
            a[i][k] /= a[k][k];
        }

        #pragma omp parallel for shared(a,n,k) private(i) schedule(static, 64)
        for(i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
            int j;
            const double aik = a[i][k]; // some compilers will do this automatically
            for(j = k + 1; j < n; j++) {
                a[i][j] -= aik * a[k][j];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Runtimes for an array of 3000x3000 `icc -O2`:

```
Your code sequential:  0:24.61 99%  CPU
Your code 8 threads :  0:05.21 753% CPU
My   code sequential:  0:18.53 99%  CPU
My   code 8 threads :  0:05.42 766% CPU
```

And on a different machine I tested it on AVX (256-bit vectors, 4 doubles per op):

```
My code on AVX sequential :  0:09.45 99%  CPU
My code on AVX 8 threads  :  0:03.92 766% CPU
```

As you can see I have improved the vectoriser a little, but didn't do much for the parallel section.

Comment: I get similar result using `gcc`/`icc`, but absolutely no performance improvement using VS2010 when enabling openmp, sse2, fp-mode:fast and full optimization, for both of your code and his code.

Comment: On which OS was tested this code?
I've tested it on Windows using MinGW: without -O or -O2 flag parrallel is faster, but if you enable one of those flags time for parallel is equal or more than sequence...

Comment: WinXP with VS2010, time for sequential and 4-thread versions are equal when enabling sse2.

Comment: "Also for some reason your #pragma omp does not start any threads unless omp_set_num_threads was invoked to actually make it use threads." is not generally true. (It is certainly not true for Intel compilers; by default we will createone thread for each available logical processor).

Comment: @JimCownie Didn't work for me until i set the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS=8` although all other code runs by default with 8 threads.

Comment: @SergeyL. Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @gerz modded Red Hat 4.4.7-3 for extra processor support on a SGI UV100

Answer (score 1):

The main problem of your code is that you decomposed the workload in a bad way.

For a single LU decomposition, you invoke parallel for `n-1` times. On each time, parallel for will do thread fork and join, which introduces a lot of overhead. Especially when `k` is large, the inner loop (`for(i){for(j){...}}`) contains only very little work. Paralleling it will be quite inefficient.

You may consider use proper agglomeration schemes to reduce the overhead. For more info please refer to this slides.

http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs554/notes/06_lu_8up.pdf

On the other hand, you could use existing performance libraries to get the max performance on LU factorization, such as Intel MKL

http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468682